# How can the y-axis in $\mathbb{R^2}$ be open?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have read that $\{(x, \frac{1}{x}): x \neq 0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

So hence the complement of this set, $\{x = 0\}$, i.e. the y-axis must be open? But we cannot put an open ball with radius $r > 0$ on any point in the $y$ axis without that ball no longer being fully contained in the y-axis. So how can it be open?

Comment: How do you draw the conclusion that the $y$-axis is open from the fact that an unrelated set is closed?

Comment: I can't understand what you're saying, because your sentence “But…” contains a triple negative.  Please make this clearer.

Comment: To be more precise: the $y$-axis is definitely *not* the complement of that set.

Comment: $\{(x,y) \; |\; x\neq 0\}$ is not the complement of the given set.  It's just a tiny part of the complement.  The complement is $\{(x,y) \;|\; xy \neq 1\}$.

Comment: I am coming off these anti-depressants, I can't think straight.

Comment: Open sets are those sets, and only those sets, that are complements of a closed set. Thus, the complement of $\{(x,\frac{1}{x}), x \neq 0\}$ is open. Neither of these sets is the $y$-axis, so your comment about the $y$-axis seems to be out of context.

Answer (score 1):

The $y$-axis can be characterized as the set
$$
\{(x,y):x=0\}
$$
and so it's closed, because the projection to the first coordinate is continuous.

This set is definitely not the complement of
$$
H=\left\{\left(x,\frac{1}{x}\right):x\ne0\right\}
$$
because, for instance, $(2,2)$ belongs to the complement of $H$ but not to the $y$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

If you draw the set $\{(x,1/x) \, | \, x \neq 0\}$ you get a very familiar graph, namely a hyperbola.  (It is also the set $\{(x,y) \, |, \, xy = 1$.)

If you google "graph of xy = 1" (as I just did) you should get lots of images.
Once you see them, you won't have trouble seeing that this graph is closed, that
it's complement is open, and that it's complement is much bigger than just the $y$-axis.